# Setting up Google Authenticator from another iOS app in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-authenticator

How to automatically launch the Google Authenticator iOS app and send data (issuer, user, secret) from Objective-c code?

This question partially solves for Swift but looking for Objective-c.
[Automatically launch Google Authenticator app on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32043500/automatically-launch-google-authenticator-app-on-ios)

Comment: if you want to use code snippet to use google aut in your app look at he link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43318487/google-authenticator-for-objective-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of iOS 9, the first thing you will need to do is whitelist the url scheme by adding this to your Info.plist

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>otpauth</string>
</array>
```

Then to launch into Google Authenticator all you should need to do is this:

```
NSString *otpString = @"otpauth://totp/Example:alice@google.com?secret=JBSWY3DPEHPK3PXP&issuer=Example";
NSURL *otpURL = [NSURL URLWithString:otpString];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:otpURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:otpURL];
}
```

• Useful [page](http://dan.hersam.com/tools/gen-qr-code.html) for generating Google Authenticator URLs.

• You can look at Google's internal code for parsing the URLs [here](https://github.com/google/google-authenticator/blob/master/mobile/ios/Classes/OTPAuthURL.m).